# Find similarity measure for feature vectors having different length

Tags: java, similarity, text-processing

In Java, how can we find similarity measure between two vectors having different length. 
Consider we have

```
V1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
V1 = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I looking for similarity measure other than Jaccard Coefficient or Sørensen–Dice coefficient

Comment: Levenshtein distance?

Comment: What do you mean under `similarity`?

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan If he knew, he wouldn't be asking. The question is as much about a good *definition* of similarity as the actual algorithm to compute it.

Comment: Normalized Levenshtein distance is good to account for differing length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone already commented, a possible alternative would be the *Levenshtein distance*, also sometimes referred to as the *edit distance*.

The Levenshtein distance is a function which assigns to every pair of strings `A` and `B` a natural number `n`, which represents the minimum number of operations need to transform `A` to `B`. The allowed operations are

1. Delete a symbol from `A`,
2. Insert a symbol into `A`,
3. Replace a symbol in `A`.

Note that the edit distance is symmetric (as for any sequence of operations that transforms `A` to `B`) it is possible to construct an "inverted" sequence of operations which transforms `B` to `A`.

The Wikipedia article on the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) lists some useful properties.

Finally, as an example, let's transform your two vectors:

```
[10011]
// Insert 1 into position 2:
[101011]
// Insert 0 into position 5:
[1010101]
// Insert 0 into position 7:
[10101010]
```

We found a sequence of 3 operations. If we manage to prove that there are no shorter sequences, then we could conclude that the distance between `V1` and `V2` is 3. Well, considering that the Levenshtein distance is always *at least* the difference in size between the two strings (think about why that is), then we have our conclusion:

```
levenshtein_distance(V1,V2) == 3 // returns true!
```

Hope this helps!